How do I connect a hose to a plastic box?
I'm a total beginner to, like, everything. I've been working on hydroponic grow tower project for ~6 months and teaching myself everything as I go along. I've gotten to a point where I really need to know how to transfer water in and out of the individual shelves within the tower. However, I'm having a lot of trouble researching this because I have no idea what I'm looking for.
The situation is as such:
The shelves in my tower are parallel, one on top of the other. I want to set up a cascade system. I need have two ~1 inch holes with watertight connectors in the back of each shelf, one to pour water in and one to pass it on (when the water level reaches it). Small strips of hose will connect the shelves via the connectors.
My shelves/containers are made of 0.06" plastic, and are screwed by their backs onto 3/4" wood. The wood can have as many holes in it as necessary.
So, to summarize, connectors fastened to 0.06" plastic container. Hose attaches to connectors and transfers water between containers. Holes/hose/connectors ~ 1 inch in diameter.
I sincerely apologize for my utter lack of knowledge regarding this topic and will appreciate whatever help/direction someone can give me.
Please let me know if I need to provide more info!
Thank you so much!
-Maya
*ps. I would attach a picture but that doesn't seem to be an option

There's an image upload button on the editor toolbar. Just leave a blank line before and after the image insert. There is also a (?) help button.

There are many types of connectors designed to go through wall, some are called bulkhead connectors.
This is one example of many:
https://www.screwfix.com/p/flomasta-brass-compression-tank-connector-22mm/36982

If a pipe is used to make a stub for your flexible pipe to push on then that works. Did exactly that for 4 rain butts in parallel.

Thank you so much! This is amazing help and provides me with some knowledge (and words) to find the right part! Thanks, again
